# What is causing Samsung NX1000 to report "No lens fitted"?

Tags: lens

I have a Samsung NX1000.

I am getting a no lens fitted sign on the screen. It is the correct lens that came with the camera. The focus also seems blurred.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you removed and put it back?

Comment: Yes tried that and tried cleaning the terminals too thanks

Comment: Did this just start? Did anything in particular happen before the problem first occurred?

Comment: Took the lens off to clean it. When replace the notification came up

Comment: Hmm. How did you clean it? Sorry to ask all of these questions, but it's hard to guess at possibilities without narrowing it down.

Comment: Soft cloth only

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried cleaning the contact points** on both the lens and the camera? Be careful though not to use any fluids that can leak into the camera (or lens). And if something is used make sure it's something that evaporates quickly. Could be a bad contact being fixed this way.

**Maybe the lens can be put on the wrong way** so that the contact points don't line up. Very unlikely but that could also be an explanation. I don't expect samsung to deliver a product that allows this though. You can check for markers on both lens and body that should be aligned on pairing the two together.

That leaves the last, more likely option of **a broken lens or camera**. These camera's are communicating with each other using these contact points but if the contacts are fine and either end is electronically malfunctioning you would still get this behaviour.

For that to be excluded you'll need another lens and/or another camera. Check if there is a shop near by where you could try switching with a demo model. Or just return it.

Blurred focus is to be expected since the camera doesn't detect the lens it also won't trigger the focus system nor the aperture to make anything of the light entering.